# Iframe does not show content on mobile

Tags: html, iframe, responsive

I have an iframe with which I am bringing PDF or JPEG documents, when I do the mobile or tablet type view, the iframe does not show the document.

This is the code I have:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="` + urlDoc.data.dir + `" width="100%" height="500" runat="server" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

This is how it looks when I open it on mobile or tablet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3zNP.png)

I would like to know if it is possible that the iframe works on mobile or is there a solution that replaces the iframe?

Thanks for readme

Comment: Is the content in the iframe loaded via an http*s* URL with a trusted certificate? If not it will be blocked. That's worth checking.

Comment: Yes, First you should test with absolute URL, and also allow IFROM in your .htaccess